# Opening another activity would hide actionbar

Tags: android, android-layout

I've created NavigationActivity (using activity gallery). 
I tried to open an activity from the drawer menu, however the the drawer menu and AppBarLayout will disappear after opening the new activity which will cover NavigationActivity

The activity I want to open is fragment based (`FragmentActivity`), how would I open it within the `NavigationActivity` ? without having to copy the xml for drawer menu and AppBarLayout ?

I hope I make it clear.

Comment: Use Fragment instead of Activity can avoid missing of part in activity

Comment: Shall I use ContentFrameLayout?

Comment: For me, i would suggest simply applying your NavigationActivity and wrap a fragment container there, simply applying fragment manager to switch fragment

Comment: I tried `transaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, new MapsActivity());` but I got error: E`no suitable method found for replace(int,MapsActivity)
method FragmentTransaction.replace(int,Fragment,String) is not applicable
(actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
method FragmentTransaction.replace(int,Fragment) is not applicable
(actual argument MapsActivity cannot be converted to Fragment by method invocation conversion)`

Comment: Make your MapsActivity into a fragment view